# Ruby - check if array of arrays contains some array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays, f.e:
`[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]`.
I want to check if this collection contains array
    `[1,2]`.
Is there any way to do so without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby's `#include?` method can be used here:

```
arr = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
arr.include?([1, 2])
# => true
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. For a long time I thought I had a problem with an array flattening, but apparently that was a bug in my own code,

Comment: `include?` is more direct, but you could instead use `arr.index([1,2])` (returns `nil` or a truthy value) or `(arr & [1,2]).any?` or `arr - [1,2] != arr` (etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `bigarray.include? smallarray`. It's the same way you'd check for membership with any other list. [Example](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P1HBViE62lBHwShWRyHaWEfBBESb6iiYxcZyJYEkwXJcBaUlxQqJepl5yTmlKan2Ckn//wMA)